# Finding Indices of Unique Elements in R

Tags: r, list, unique

Brain not working well today. I have a data frame as follows:

```
  V1   V2
1  8  200
2  8  200
3  8  200
4  8  200
5 34  250
6  8 2500
```

I'd like to return a list, with each element of the list containing a vector of the indices of each unique pair of elements in my data frame. The list should look like:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196710/r-find-indices-of-each-unique-item-in-list) thread - quite similar - yet still stumped.

Thanks in advance SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `mydf` is your dataframe, and that you're okay with character values being returned for your rownames, you can try:

```
> lapply(split(mydf, list(mydf$V1, mydf$V2), drop=TRUE), row.names)
$`8.200`
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

$`34.250`
[1] "5"

$`8.2500`
[1] "6"
```

Otherwise a little wordier:

```
> lapply(split(mydf, list(mydf$V1, mydf$V2), drop=TRUE),
         function(x) as.numeric(row.names(x)))
$`8.200`
[1] 1 2 3 4

$`34.250`
[1] 5

$`8.2500`
[1] 6
```

Note: Of course, if you have rownames that do not correspond to the row number in your original dataframe, you can't use these as extraction indices.

Comment: Almost the exact same answer I was about to post +1!

Comment: While they may be in this example, be careful that row.names aren't always numeric. It's often best just to keep them as character since you can just as easily subset that way as well. Indexes and row.names can be quite distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting by a  combination  the 2 columns:

```
split(seq_len(nrow(dat)),paste(dat$V1,dat$V2,sep='/'))

$`34/250`
[1] 5

$`8/200`
[1] 1 2 3 4

$`8/2500`
[1] 6
```

Comment: +1 You could also do: `split(seq_len(nrow(dat)),list(dat$V1,dat$V2), drop=TRUE)`

Comment: +1 brillant use of `drop=TRUE`. I don't know this one !

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using `tapply` and `interaction` assuming your data.frame is named `dd`

```
with(dd, tapply(seq.int(nrow(dd)), interaction(V1, V2, drop=T), 
    identity, simplify=F))

# $`8.200`
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# $`34.250`
# [1] 5
# 
# $`8.2500`
# [1] 6
```